# Is it possible to track state update after firing event in React Native project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library

The main component AccordionItem.tsx:

```
import { LayoutChangeEvent, Pressable, View, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';
import { useEvoComponentTheme } from '../theme';
import React, { forwardRef, ReactElement, useMemo } from 'react';
import Animated, {
  FadeIn,
  FadeOut,
  LinearTransition,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  withTiming,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import { Icon } from '../Icon';
import { Checkbox } from '../Checkbox';
import { Switch } from '../Switch';
import {
  AccordionHeaderProps,
  AccordionItemHeader,
} from './AccordionItemHeader';
import { spacings } from '../theme/theme.spacings';
import { FontAwesomeIconStyle } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
import { IconPrefix } from '@fortawesome/pro-thin-svg-icons';
import { IconName } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons';

export interface AccordionItemProps {
  isExpanded: boolean;
  setIsExpanded: (value: boolean) => void;
  action?: 'drag' | 'checkbox' | 'switch';
  toggleValue?: boolean;
  onToggleValueChange?: (newValue: boolean) => unknown;
  header:
    | (Pick<AccordionHeaderProps, 'title'> & Partial<AccordionHeaderProps>)
    | ReactElement;
  containerStyle?: ViewStyle;
  onLayout?: (event: LayoutChangeEvent) => void;
  content?: ReactElement;
  expandIcon?: [IconPrefix, IconName];
  expandIconRotate?: boolean;
}

export const AccordionItem = forwardRef(
  (
    {
      isExpanded,
      setIsExpanded,
      action,
      toggleValue,
      onToggleValueChange,
      header,
      containerStyle,
      onLayout,
      content,
    }: AccordionItemProps,
    ref: React.ForwardedRef<Animated.View> | undefined
  ) => {
    const style = useEvoComponentTheme('AccordionItem', {});

    const expandIconAnimatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
      transform: [
        {
          rotate: withTiming(isExpanded ? '180deg' : '0deg'),
        },
      ],
    }));

    const actionElement = useMemo<ReactElement | null>(() => {
      switch (action) {
        case 'checkbox':
          if (typeof toggleValue !== 'boolean' || !onToggleValueChange) {
            throw Error(`
              Provide 'toggleValue' and 'onToggleValueChange' to control checkbox in the AccordionItem.
              Uncontrollable checkbox is not supported.
            `);
          }

          return (
            <Animated.View
              layout={LinearTransition}
              style={[style.actionContainer]}
              testID={'checkboxContainer'}
            >
              <Checkbox
                checked={toggleValue}
                onChange={() => {
                  onToggleValueChange(!toggleValue);
                }}
                containerStyle={{
                  ...style.action,
                  ...style.actionToggle,
                }}
              />
            </Animated.View>
          );
        case 'switch':
          if (typeof toggleValue !== 'boolean' || !onToggleValueChange) {
            throw Error(`
              Provide 'toggleValue' and 'onToggleValueChange' to control switch in the AccordionItem.
              Uncontrollable switch is not supported.
            `);
          }

          return (
            <Animated.View
              layout={LinearTransition}
              style={[style.actionContainer]}
              testID={'switchContainer'}
            >
              <Switch
                checked={toggleValue}
                onChange={() => {
                  onToggleValueChange(!toggleValue);
                }}
                containerStyle={{
                  ...style.action,
                  ...style.actionToggle,
                }}
                icon="check"
              />
            </Animated.View>
          );
        case 'drag':
          return (
            <Animated.View
              layout={LinearTransition}
              style={[style.actionContainer]}
              testID={'dragContainer'}
            >
              <View
                style={
                  {
                    ...style.action,
                    ...style.actionDrag,
                  } as FontAwesomeIconStyle
                }
              >
                <Icon icon={['fal', 'grip-lines']} size="sm" />
              </View>
            </Animated.View>
          );
        default:
          return null;
      }
    }, [
      action,
      toggleValue,
      onToggleValueChange,
      style.actionContainer,
      style.action,
      style.actionToggle,
      style.actionDrag,
    ]);

    return (
      <Animated.View
        layout={LinearTransition}
        style={[style.container, containerStyle]}
        ref={ref}
        onLayout={onLayout}
      >
        {actionElement}

        <View
          style={[
            style.mainContainer,
            !action && {
              paddingLeft: spacings.md,
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Pressable
            onPress={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)}
            style={[style.headerWrapper]}
            testID="headerWrapper"
          >
            <View style={[style.headerContainer]}>
              {React.isValidElement(header) ? (
                header
              ) : (
                <AccordionItemHeader
                  isExpanded={isExpanded}
                  noContent={!content}
                  {...header}
                />
              )}
            </View>
            <Animated.View
              layout={LinearTransition}
              style={[style.expandIconContainer, expandIconAnimatedStyle]}
            >
              <Icon
                icon={['fal', 'chevron-down']}
                size="sm"
                style={[style.expandIcon] as FontAwesomeIconStyle}
              />
            </Animated.View>
          </Pressable>

          {
            content &&
            <Animated.View
              style={[style.contentContainer, !isExpanded && { display: 'none' }]}
              entering={FadeIn.duration(800)}
              exiting={FadeOut}
              testID="contentContainer"
            >
              {content}
            </Animated.View>
          }
        </View>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
);
```

The component I want to track state in (Checkbox.tsx):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Pressable, View, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';
import { useEvoComponentTheme } from '../theme';
import { Icon } from '../Icon';
import { FontAwesomeIconStyle } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';

export interface CheckboxProps {
  checked: boolean;
  onChange: (value: boolean) => void;
  isDisabled?: boolean;
  containerStyle?: ViewStyle;
  testID?: string;
  accessibilityLabel?: string;
}

export const Checkbox = ({
  checked,
  onChange,
  isDisabled = false,
  containerStyle,
  testID = 'CheckBoxTestID',
  accessibilityLabel,
}: CheckboxProps) => {
  const style = useEvoComponentTheme('Checkbox', {});
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState<boolean>(checked);

  const handleValueChange = () => {
    setIsActive((prevState) => !prevState);
    onChange?.(!isActive);
  };

  const renderCheckbox = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          ...style.checkboxContainer,
          ...(isActive && style.checkboxContainerActive),
          ...(isDisabled && style.checkboxContainerDisabled),
        }}
        testID={`${testID} container`}
      >
        {isActive ? (
          <Icon
            icon={['fas', 'check']}
            size={'sm'}
            style={
              {
                ...style.icon,
                ...(isDisabled && style.iconDisabled),
              } as FontAwesomeIconStyle
            }
            testID={`${testID} icon`}
          />
        ) : null}
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Pressable
      style={{
        ...style.container,
        ...containerStyle,
      }}
      onPress={handleValueChange}
      disabled={isDisabled}
      testID={testID}
      accessible
      accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
      accessibilityRole={'checkbox'}
      accessibilityState={{ disabled: isDisabled, checked }}
    >
      {renderCheckbox()}
    </Pressable>
  );
};
```

Tests:

```
describe('<AccordionItem />', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    const component = renderAccordionItem();
    expect(component.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('should properly render header action', async () => {
    const onToggleValueChange = jest.fn();

    const checkboxCollapsedAccordionItem = renderAccordionItem({
      action: 'checkbox',
      toggleValue: false,
      onToggleValueChange,
    });

    const checkboxEl =
      checkboxCollapsedAccordionItem.getByTestId('checkboxContainer')
        .children[0].children[0];

    fireEvent.press(checkboxEl);

    expect(onToggleValueChange).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(onToggleValueChange).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(true);

    console.log(
      checkboxCollapsedAccordionItem.getByTestId('checkboxContainer')
        .children[0].props.checked
    );
  });
});
```

The test is valid, which means I get necessary node and my callback properly triggers the callback. But all the same, I get 'false' in my log, whereas it should be 'true' after handler execution. Maybe the reason is that console is run before state could be updated, but I struggled to validate this idea.

Thank you in advance for any help!